# ElasticSearch 'Fields' does not returns any fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to access specific fields from ElasticSearch depending on the query.

Below is my index structure -

```
    {
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "Color": {
          "type": "string", "index":"not_analyzed"
        },
        "Name": {
          "type": "string", "index":"not_analyzed"
        },
        "ListPrice": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "StandardCost": {
          "type": "double"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

below is the query with _source -

```
{
"from" : 0,
"size" : 20,
"_source": [ "Name"],
"query" : { "term" : {"Name" : "Mountain"} }
}
```

Here are sample documents -

```
{
    "Color": "Green",
    "Name": "Mountain Views",
    "ListPrice": 4.00,
    "StandardCost": 8.00
}


{
    "Color": "Green",
    "Name": "Mountain Views",
    "ListPrice": 4.00,
    "StandardCost": 8.00
}


{
    "Color": "Green",
    "Name": "Mountain Views",
    "ListPrice": 4.00,
    "StandardCost": 8.00
}
```

I get the ids in results but I don't get 'Name' field.

Also I tried using 'fields' property but I still don't get 'Name' field back.

Can someone help me?

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: Can you show a sample document that you have indexed?

Comment: Have you ensured that the `Name` field is having *mountain* value? and if yes please then the `fields` would work, and return you the results.

Comment: Please have a look on this [Reference]  (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html#search-request-fields)

Comment: I have updated the post with sample documents.